# Bootstrap carousel images are not reponsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

i'm building a website with bootstrap with the carousel template. I have an issue with the images inside the carousel: when i resize the browser window they get stretched and so the look awful. I didn't modify the default bootstrap css and html values. How can i fix this problem?

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 670px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 670px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #777; 
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 850px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? This will happen to low quality images. As you stretch a low quality image the quality decreases further.

Comment: Ok, done. Do you also need the html?

Comment: Have you used the class `img-responsive` on the images? Do you want the images to resize to the browser size or remain as they are?

Comment: No,  I didn't use the img-responsive class and if I try to add it i see no results at all. I want the images to be reponsive and to resize when i resize the browser window.